# Chatting using socket.io

Tags: android, socket.io

I am preparing chatting application using `socket.io`. Anyone can provide tutorial or guidance to preparing chatting application using `socket.io`? I have searched for tutorials. I can't find step by step tutorial. Please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this library its works for my chat application

[Gottox-socket.io](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client)

first step copy package io.socket from gottox library to your project

then create your socket.io connection to API server like this

```
  SocketIO socket = new SocketIO("http://10.0.2.2:8000/");
    socket.connect(new IOCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMessage(JSONObject json, IOAcknowledge ack) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Server said:" + json.toString(2));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(String data, IOAcknowledge ack) {
            System.out.println("Server said: " + data);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(SocketIOException socketIOException) {
            System.out.println("an Error occured");
            socketIOException.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnect() {
            System.out.println("Connection terminated.");
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnect() {
            System.out.println("Connection established");
        }

        @Override
        public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... args) {
            System.out.println("Server triggered event '" + event + "'");
          //I got receive_message from server here
          //to get string response i parse it to object array 
           Object[] arguments = args;
           System.out.println(args[0]);
        }
    });
```

and if you want to send a message use this

```
socket.send("Hello Server!");
```

and last don't forget to prepare your API server